# How can I change only my array when I click in a button?

Tags: html, angular

I have a array with animals. For the moment I can display all the animal in a array but I want to display only some animals when I click on a button.

This is my html code :

```
<br>
<table>
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Nos especes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let a of especeAnimalPresente">
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="animated-button1">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            {{a}}
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<table class="table" style="color:white">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Espece</th>
        <th scope="col">Nom</th>
        <th scope="col">Sexe</th>
        <th scope="col">Signe distinctif</th>
        <th scope="col">Bilan de sante</th>
        <th scope="col">Date arrivee</th>
        <th scope="col">Date depart</th>
        <th scope="col">Taille</th>
        <th scope="col">Age</th>
        <th scope="col">Bassin d'appartenance</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let a of animaux">
          <th scope="row">{{a.id}}</th>
          <td>{{a.espece}}</td>
          <td>{{a.nom}}</td>
          <td>{{a.sexe}}</td>
          <td>{{a.signeDistinctif}}</td>
          <td>{{a.bilanSante}}</td>
          <td>{{a.dateArr}}</td>
          <td>{{a.dateDep}}</td>
          <td>{{a.taille}}</td>
          <td>{{a.age}}</td>
          <td>{{a.bassinAppartenance}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

and this is the code in my animal.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AnimalService } from "./animal.service";
import { Animal } from "./animal";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-animal',
  templateUrl: './animal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./animal.component.css']
})
export class AnimalComponent implements OnInit {

  private animaux:Array<Animal>;
  private especeAnimalPresente:Array<string>;
  private especeAnimalPresenteTmp:Array<string>;
  constructor(private animalService: AnimalService) { 
    this.especeAnimalPresenteTmp = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.recupAllAnimals();
  }

  recupAllAnimals(){
    this.animalService.getAllAnimaux().subscribe(data => {
      this.animaux = data;
      this.recupEspecePresent();
    })

  }

  recupEspecePresent(){
     if (this.animaux){
      for (let animal of this.animaux) {
          this.especeAnimalPresenteTmp.push(animal.espece);
      }
      this.especeAnimalPresente = this.removeDuplicates(this.especeAnimalPresenteTmp);
     }
  }

  removeDuplicates(array) {
    let unique = {};
    array.forEach(function(i) {
      if(!unique[i]) {
        unique[i] = true;
      }
    });
    return Object.keys(unique);
  }

}
```

For the moment I have this result :

[image: page web with button and all animals]

I want to change only the array when I clic on a button.

Someone can help me please ?

Comment: you need to be specific on the function and what change you want on the array...

Comment: For the moment my array display 3 animals (shark, turtle, and whale). I want to display only sharks if I clic on the shark button, or only turtles if I clic on the turtle button, or only whales if I clic on the whale button.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so:

```
<a href="#" class="animated-button1" (click)="$event.preventDefault(); filterAnimals(a)">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  {{a}}
</a>
```

and in your controller:

```
filterAnimals(animal) {
  this.animaux = this.animaux.filter(el => el.espece === animal.espece)
}
```

maybe use another variable like `this.filteredAnimals` so you can still have the whole list in `this.animaux`